# Keep a history of transactions for easy rollback

Tags: transaction, log, rollback, checkpoint

Is there a database (either SQL or NoSQL) which allows you to keep a history or log of all past transactions so that you can easily rollback to any given point in time (similar to how git manages a source repository)? Taking a checkpoint after every transaction probably will do the same job, but keeping a history looks more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server with database in `FULL` recovery model permits you to do a `point-in-time restore`.

There is no need in "Taking a checkpoint after every transaction" because of `write ahead logging`.

To know more about it you can read the followin article: [SQL Server point in time restore](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/119/sql-server-point-in-time-restore/)

> **Overview**
>
> The `RESTORE ... WITH STOPAT` option allows you to restore your
>   database to a point in time.  This gives you the ability to restore a
>   database prior to an event that occurred that was detrimental to your
>   database.  In order for this option to work, the database needs to be
>   either in the `FULL` or `Bulk-Logged` recovery model and you need to be
>   doing transaction log backups.

And here is the official documentation:
[Restore a SQL Server Database to a Point in Time (Full Recovery Model)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-sql-server-database-to-a-point-in-time-full-recovery-model?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

All major relational databases support this. The concept is known as "point in time recovery".

In Postgres this is done using [WAL archiving](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html).

In Oracle this is done by running in [archivelog mode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/managing-archived-redo-log-files.html#GUID-36F3335E-A28B-47BA-82C2-E17B4C8A453A).

Additionally Oracle supports so called "flashback" operations that can be applied on different levels, e.g. [flashback database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/FLASHBACK-DATABASE.html#GUID-BE0ACF9A-BC13-4810-B08B-33326440258B)

For SQL Server, see [sepupic's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/223410)